# Angular2, RouteParams not working

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, typescript1.7

I'm getting a error that is currently causing lots of frustration. Here's what I running with:

- **ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC1**
- **Angular2, 2.0.0-beta.15**
- **TypeScript, 1.7.6.0**

---

The error(s):

```
Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
Attempting redirect to: /Design/0DEAC46A-7F58-49F9-B67E-2C187DFA49A7/
Navigated to http://localhost:5000/
EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.
EXCEPTION: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.
STACKTRACE:
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.
    at resolvePromise (angular2-polyfills.js:602)
    at angular2-polyfills.js:638
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular2-polyfills.js:423)
    at Object.NgZoneImpl.inner.inner.fork.onInvokeTask (angular2.js:2118)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (angular2-polyfills.js:422)
    at Zone.runTask (angular2-polyfills.js:320)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (angular2-polyfills.js:541)
    at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:493)
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable. ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoAnnotationError {message: "Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?)… that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.", stack: "Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RoutePar…//localhost:5000/js/angular2/angular2.js:9448:46)"}
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.(…)
Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable. ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: NoAnnotationError {message: "Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?)… that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.", stack: "Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RoutePar…//localhost:5000/js/angular2/angular2.js:9448:46)"}
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters for 'RouteParams'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'RouteParams' is decorated with Injectable.(…)
```

I have an abstract base class that has two subclasses, acting as **Angular2** components. Each have a constructor that takes the `RouteParams` instance. Subclass one works just fine, but subclass two fails to load with the error message above.

The `RouteDefinition` is actually an `AsyncRoute` that is defined with a path like so: `path: '/:appId/:customerId/'`

Here is a screen capture from an error thrown in Angular when it attempts to reflect on `RouteParams`.

[image]

---

Base class:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {RouteParams, Location} from "angular2/router";
import {CustomerService} from "../../shared/services/customer.service";

@Component({
    providers: [CustomerService]
})

export abstract class BaseCustomerSelectorComponent implements OnInit {
    protected params: RouteParams;

    constructor(private customerService: CustomerService,
                private routeParams: RouteParams,
                private ngLocation: Location) {
        this.params = routeParams;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // omitted..
    }
}
```

Subclass Two:

```
import {Component} from "angular2/core";
import {RouteParams, Location} from "angular2/router";
import {BaseCustomerSelectorComponent} from "../../shared/components/base-customer-selector.component";
import {CustomerService} from "../../shared/services/customer.service";

@Component({
    selector: "customer-selector",
    templateUrl: "app/shell/templates/customer-selector.html",
    styleUrls: ["app/shell/styles/customer-selector.css"],
    providers: [CustomerService, Settings, RouteParams]
})

export class CustomerSelectorComponent extends BaseCustomerSelectorComponent {
    constructor(customerService: CustomerService,
                routeParams: RouteParams,
                ngLocation: Location) {
        super(customerService, routeParams, ngLocation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you put the actual code

Comment: `RouteParams` can only be injected in components that are added by the router. Otherwise what @kemsky said. Ensure that `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` are added **only** on the root component (or alternatively **only** in `bootstra()`)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer, please provide an answer as you are the one that is correct.  The issue is that of the two subclass components, the one that errors out is not added by the router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`RouteParams` can only be injected in components that are added by the router.

In other components you can inject the `Router` and subscribe to it`

```
  constructor(private router:Router) {
    router.subscribe(route => {
      console.debug(this.router.currentInstruction.component.params);
    });
  }
```

Otherwise what @kemsky said.

Ensure that `ROUTER_PROVIDERS` are added only on the root component (or alternatively only in bootstrap())

Comment: The was certainly the "`RouteParams` can only be injected in components that are added by the router." I wish that was documented in the **Angular2** docs.  Thank you!

Comment: The router is still work-in-progress. I guess they don't want to spend too much time to document things that may change at any time.

Comment: Are you familiar with any builtin way in **Angular2** to parse a URL from a component that doesn't have a `Router` or `RouteParams`? I saw `URLSearchParams` but that seems to be only for query string.

Comment: I think it was mentioned recently that something like that might be added to `Location`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `RouteParams` from providers, injection should use inherited instance.

Well, check `super` call, it seems that parameters have wrong order, settings is redundant.

Comment: try adding `ROUTER_PROVIDERS`

Comment: Tried that too, followed all of the examples and spent a day searching the web for it. Nothing obvious is going to be the answer, I think there is a bug with the base class somehow?