# Angular - optional route param ngRouter

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, angular-router

I'm using Angular (4) with the @angular/router and want to be able to have optional parameters in a path style.

I currently have this:

```
{ path: 'cars', component: CarComponent },
{ path: 'cars/:type', component: CarComponent },
{ path: 'cars/:type/:brand', component: CarComponent },
{ path: 'cars/:type/:brand/:id', component: CarComponent },
```

This works but what I'm looking for is an optional parameter in **:type**. The type can either be **'new'** or empty so **' '** and the empty part is the one that seems hard to do because Angular doesn't know what the context is.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Have you looked at this thread?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208745/angular-2-optional-route-parameter

Answer (score 0):

You are doing RESTful conceptually wrong.
/cars would take you to a list of cars where you can filter by type or brand.
/cars/:id would take you to the car that you selected from the list.