# Making Angular 2 params optional, so that it doesn't show in URL.

Tags: angular

My issue is closest to [THIS POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208745/angular-2-optional-route-parameter). But, it'a slightly a different scenario.

**SCENARIO**

I have 2 pages **main** and **detail**.

- To visit the **main** page, I visit http://localhost:3000/main
- To visit the **detail** page, I visit http://localhost:3000/detail

Now, in the **main** page, I have a drop-down the has initially no value selected.

And, in the **details** page I have a BACK link that points back to **main** page

**CODE**

**ROUTES**

```
{
  path: 'main',
  component: SomeComponent
},
{
  path: 'main/:dropdown_value',
  component: SomeComponent
}
```

**DETAIL TEMPLATE**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/main', selectedDropDownValue]">BACK</a>
```

The `selectedDropDownValue` comes from component and contains the dropdown's selected value from the **main** page.

**PROBLEM**

The above implementation works like charm. So, when I hit back the **main** page, based on the params I passed, I re-select the last selected dropdown value. But, now the main URL becomes:

http://localhost:3000/main/abc

Here, `abc` is the selected dropdown value

But, I want the URL to stay like

http://localhost:3000/main

It shouldn't show /abc at the end

Answer (score 0):

when we don't want to show data in the URL path than we have to send data via routing using data property of the @RouteConfig annotation provided by angualr2. by using this property we can send additional data to the components at the time of the route configuration without showing it in the URL. here is example of this property.

You can pass the data like this:

```
[routerLink]="['/ProductDetail', {id:1234}]
```

The configuration route:

```
{path: 'product/:id', component: ProductDetailComponentParam ,
                      data: [{isProd: true}]}
```

Get the data:

```
constructor(params: RouteParams, data: RouteData){
        this.productID = params.get('id');

        console.log("Is this prod environment?" + data.get('isProd'));
    }
```

More info on this article:

https://yakovfain.com/2015/11/11/angular-2-passing-data-to-routes/

Comment: `[routerLink]="['/main', {dropdown_value:'abc'}]`, now shows the URL like **http://192.168.3.4:3000/main;dropdown_value=abc**, which is not what I want.

Comment: Yes sorry, reading the docs, i can see the data on router is reintroduced on angular 4.0.0 version. In angular 2 you cant pass data this way. Best option to achieve is a shared service.