# how to set optional parameter in base href element in angular

Tags: angular

Hi i want an optional parameter to be set in so that any of below URL will respond

http://myWebsiteName/mango/myRouterPath or
http://myWebsiteName/myRouterPath

where mango is optional

Comment: Add more details of you problem and refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example of how to [set optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208745/angular-2-optional-route-parameter), but does your use case need to have mango in the center of the url? It makes more sense to have something like myWebsite/page/drilldown or myWebsite/page/:dependency instead of of myWebsite/:dependency/page