# Angular2+ routing - optional route params

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing

So I have routes like `/category/tech` and `/category/tech/new` and `/category/tech/old` etc

they all use `ItemsComponent`

So is there any way to define these type routes with optional params like we do in ExpressJS

```
router.get('/category/tech/:filter?', (req, res) => ...
```

(here both `/category/tech` and `/category/tech/xxx` will work)

Or do I have to define them separately like

```
{path: 'users', component: ItemsComponent},
{path: 'users/:filter', component: ItemsComponent}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 optional route parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208745/angular-2-optional-route-parameter)

Comment: check this https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/parameterised-routes/#_optional_params

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> So is there any way to define these type routes with optional params
>   like we do in ExpressJS

Simple answer is No, you have to define new route for each separate path.

```
{path: 'users', component: ItemsComponent},
{path: 'users/:filter', component: ItemsComponent}
```

Though you can verify the path and determine, if it has optional parameter inside the routed `component` using `ActivatedRoute`.

Answer (score 9):

As of now, Angular does not let you define optional parameters. So your solution will be to add multiple similar routes - all pointing to the same component. But there is an important thing to note here. If you use the target as `component: ItemsComponent` in both routes, since the routes are different, the component will be re-instantiated! - That could be costly depending on your project. If you do not want to re- instantiate the component for every route use `redirect` instead. In this case Angular makes sure that the component is instantiated only once.

```
{path: 'users', redirectTo: 'users/'},
{path: 'users/:filter', component: ItemsComponent}
```

Hope this helps!