# Getting issue optional parameter outing issue in angular 4?

Tags: angular

Routing issue when i try with "http://localhost:4200/Search-result" but its not redirect. Can you please say me what is wrong with it? Its Redirect to Home page path.

```
 { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
 {
    path: 'search-result',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: SearchResultComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'search-result/:searchText',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: SearchResultComponent
  }
```

Comment: whether other routes are working..?

Comment: what's the error u r getting in console

Comment: nothing getting error in console when i was call http://localhost:4200/Search-result then its redirect to me home page path. yes other i was create url its working fine for me { path: 'login', pathMatch: 'full', component: LoginComponent }, its working

Comment: i think you don't pass the searchText in route navigate. something like ```[routerLink]="'search-result/' + searchText"```

Comment: on redirecting whether browser page is refreshing

Answer (score 0):

https://angular.io/api/router/Routes

You are using pathMatch: 'full' which means, that the whole URL path needs to match and is consumed by the route matching algorithm.

and in your URL 'http://localhost:4200/Search-result' ":searchText" is not passed. Henceforth it is redirecting to default route.

Note there is one more possible value for pathMatch:
pathMatch: 'prefix' means, the first route where the path matches the start of the URL is choosen, but then the route matching algorithm is continuing searching for matching child routes where the rest of the URL matches

Comment: but I was create another routes for searchText. see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208745/angular-2-optional-route-parameter         another link for same https://elanderson.net/2017/01/angular-2-optional-route-parameter/

Comment: And i was remove pathMatch: 'full' and check it but it didn't work for me

Comment: Can you try using  'http://localhost:4200/search-result' ". "S" is capital in "search-result". Try changing it to lowercase.