# How to add token parameter to angular route?

Tags: angular

I have Angular-12 frontend and Laravel-8 backend project for user registration confirmation with token.

From the api backend, I route into the Angular frontend this way for user activation through email:

> ->action('Confirm Account', url('https://myapp/auth/signup/activate?token='.$notifiable->activation_token))

But my Angular app-routing module has:

app-routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: 'home', loadChildren: () => import('./features/landings/landings.module').then(m => m.LandingsModule)},
  {path: 'auth', loadChildren: () => import('./features/auth/auth.module').then(m => m.AuthModule)},
];
```

auth-routing-module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '',
  component: LoginComponent,
  children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'signup/activate',
    component: SignupConfirmComponent
}
]}];
```

But whenever the user clicks on the notification sent to the email:

> https://myapp/auth/signup/activate?token=8774945

I got this error from the frontend:

> 404 Not Found

What else do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your routes need to look like this:

```typescript
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '',
  component: LoginComponent,
  children: [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AuthComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'signup/activate/:id',
    component: SignupConfirmComponent
}
]}];
```

Note the `path: 'signup/activate/:id'` line

Then make the link look like this:
`https://myapp/auth/signup/activate/8774945`

In your router code you will have something like this:

```typescript
export class SignupConfirmComponent implements OnInit {
  id: string
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')
  }
}
```

You can find a more detailed explanation of how routes with parameters are used in the [Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/start/start-routing)

Your backend PHP code should probably look like this. Disclaimer: I am not a PHP programmer.

```php
->action('Confirm Account', url('https://myapp/auth/signup/activate/'.$notifiable->activation_token))
```

Comment: Sorry about this question. How do I re-write the route that goes to the email from the backend api:     ->action('Confirm Account', url('https://myapp/auth/signup/activate?token='.$notifiable->activation_token))

Comment: I do not know PHP so I added a guess based on what you put up that will probably work.

Comment: I got this error      Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.      in   this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')    and this.id is highlighted

Comment: You are probably not including the token in the url.  You can make the parameter optional as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208745/angular-2-optional-route-parameter