# How to make angular route parameter optional

Tags: angular

What I would like to do is simply following:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/user/:id', component: User, name: 'User' },
    { path: '/user', component: User, name: 'User' }
]);
```

As you can see, that `:id` is optional. Somehow I get the feeling that this code example can be shortened, something like this:

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/user/:id?', component: User, name: 'User' }
]);
```

BTW, this doesn't work, but it should express what I'm thinking. Is something like this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 2 optional route parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34208745/angular-2-optional-route-parameter)

Comment: I saw that post too, its a bit old and the solution provided there are all inline with my first code example.

Comment: As far as I know, nothing changed in this regard, so the answers are still up-to-date. Also there are alternative answers, for example the one with the redirect.